# SQL Server Enterprise vs IBM iSeries as400 reliability and performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, db2, ibm-midrange

having a bit of a difficult time drumming up a good comparison between these two enterprise level systems. I'm wondering if anyone has ever come up with some concrete statistics between the two. Does anyone here know performance benchmarks between the two? Looking for reliability (up time), access speeds... things of that nature. The struggle is that most information that presents itself is always opinion based - looking for concrete facts regarding the two.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/05/the-dewitt-clause-why-you-rarely-see-database-benchmarks/

Comment: One consideration might be the availability of expertise in your market. If one tech stack has a higher penetration regionally, you'll find it easier to hire talent for that system than for another. Irrelevant if you're in a big enough market, but a real factor for lots of businesses. Local schools will willingly share what platforms they're teaching on (and are often influenced by area businesses that might not tell _you_ what they're using).

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what has already been posted you can't really do a apples to oranges comparison between those 2 environments. IBM's offering (which is actually Power Systems running IBM i OS) is a "self-contained" all-in-one whereas any SQL Server system there are simply too many ways to impact performance and stability depending on the hardware that the SQL Server DB is running on. running benchmarks to prove/disprove the viability of running your company's business isn't going to be an easy job...